# Google Directions API - optimal route

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api

I have 4 places - origin, destination and 2 waypoints. I am trying to make Google Directions API call to get the most optimal route through those two waypoints. The problem is that Google API doesn't reorder my waypoints according to the optimal route, but it creates a route including the waypoints in the initial order that I defined in the call.

The wanted route is as following:

1. Origin
2. Waypoint 2
3. Waypoint 1
4. Destination

Received route output is as following:

1. Origin
2. Waypoint 1
3. Waypoint 2
4. Destination

Here is the API call I tried: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=46.3526877,16.8123505&destination=46.3091764,16.3420242&waypoints=optimize:true%7Cvia:46.3380636%2C16.6129778%7Cvia:46.3258985%2C16.7827804&alternatives=true&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

I tried adding "optimizeWaypoints" parameter but I always get an empty "waypoint_order" array (which should contain waypoints in the correct order so that the route will be optimal according to the documentation).

Here is the API call with "optimizeWaypoints" parameter added:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=46.3526877,16.8123505&destination=46.3091764,16.3420242&waypoints=via:46.3380636%2C16.6129778%7Cvia:46.3258985%2C16.7827804&alternatives=true&optimizeWaypoints=true&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting stopover to true for your waypoints. This is what I had to do to.
[Link to Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Google maps does not automatically optimize routes for multiple destinations. You got to use Google distance matrix api or something similar. Try this: https://d3o9xul5a19dde.cloudfront.net
There is an API as well, in addition to web interface.